# Wave Analytics Dashboard developername

Tags: einstein-analytics, analytics-cloud

How to find out what is the developername value for a wave dashboard?

Thanks.

Comment: If you are looking for the label, thats the first thing you will find when you edit (Ctrl +E) the dashboard {
    "label": "CONTACT_US_DASHBOARD",
    "state": {
        "dataSourceLinks": [],
        "gridLayouts": [
            {

Answer (score 1):

The easiest is on a dashboard to switch to JSON Editor via CRTL+E, at the top of the JSON you can see the developer name.

https://docs.releasenotes.salesforce.com/en-us/spring16/release-notes/rn_bi_dashboard_create_query.htm

Answer (score 0):

Looking at [Dashboards List Resource](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.bi_dev_guide_rest.meta/bi_dev_guide_rest/bi_resources_dashboards.htm) you could use the REST API to iterate the available Wave Dashboards.

From the example response the keyprefix for a Wave Dashboard is 0FK. You could check the Partner API for the corresponding sObject. If it is exposed a SOQL query could also iterate the available dashboards.

Answer (score 0):

1. Login to Workbench (https://workbench.developerforce.com/login.php)
2. Go to Utility --> Rest Explorer.
3. Search /services/data/v56.0/wave/dashboards --> Execute.
4. Expand the dashboard which you want to check the developer Name.
5. Expand Created By.
   There you can see the Developer name who created the dashboard. Also you can check Last Modified By name also.

[image]
[image]